# Give fixed width to td, th if width goes more than the screen then scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table in which initially there are 7 Columns and 4 rows. 
I want fixed width to td and th.
The challenge is I am adding dynamically columns and row in table and I am successful in that the problem I am facing is I am unable to control the width of td, th.
Initially I am giving 100% width to table, thead and tbody, and 15% width to td, th.

Here is my CSS:

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    thead {
        width: 100%;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    tbody {
        width: 100%;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    td{
        width: 15%;
    }
    th{
        width: 15%;
    }
```

Here is my table:

```
<section class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table border="1px" class="fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is the output I am getting now]

What I want is to give 15% width to td, th and if the total width of td, th cross 100 then a scroller should come and no change on width of th, td.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
 table {
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th div
 {
   width:150px;  //give here your approximate width
 }
```

change html to

```
<section class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table border="1px" class="fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                        <th><div>Amount</div></th>
                        <th><div>Interest Rate</div></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Banking Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Interest Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i also want to give fixed width to td th. 15%. If the width of all td, th exceeds more than 100% than scrollbar should come.

Comment: You give a try this code if th exceeds automatically a scroll bar comes

Comment: still didn't get what i wanted. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7uM0pfxiBlLeDNIN1dNX2NidlU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168444/discussion-between-lucky-bastard-and-afsal-c).